# How to disable pagination for AWS CLI help output?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I want to display some help text, and search it with grep.

`aws ec2 help | grep instance`

AWS CLI uses `more` to paginate the help.

To disable it I've already tried:

`aws --no-cli-pager ec2 help | grep instance`

`export AWS_PAGER=''; aws ec2 help | grep instance`

and changing `cli_pager` in config file:

```
[default]
cli_pager=
```

It still uses the pager.

I'm using AWS CLIv2 Windows version on Cygwin.

How does one disable it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways to disable pagination in the AWS CLI.

**1: Using the `cli_pager` option in the `config` file:**

```
[default]
cli_pager=
```

**2: Using the `AWS_PAGER` environment variable:**

```
$ export AWS_PAGER=""
```

Please note: They only work if you’re using the AWS CLI version 2. They aren’t available if you run AWS CLI version 1. For information on how to install version 2, see [Installing, updating, and uninstalling the AWS CLI version 2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2.html).

Comment: Yes, I've already tried these, as mentioned in the question. Don't seem to work with `aws-cli/2.1.7 Python/3.7.9 Windows`. Maybe these only apply to Linux version?

Comment: It seems to be doing a smart autodetection. If I pipe the output to grep or less it switches off the pager. But insists on using `more` otherwise, regardless of what flags or config I specify.

Comment: You can also directly set cli_pager=less in the config. Sure that solve the issue?

Comment: None of the flags, options or config work, might be an issue with Cygwin, which operates a Linux like environment on Windows. I'm pressed for time so don't want to bother with it, instead would run AWS CLI on another Linux based EC2 instance.

Comment: Sounds like a plan.

Answer (score 3):

There is in fact no well-supported way to do this for the special case of the help output.  The help output is treated specially by the v2 aws-cli and ignores the configured cli_pager gadgetry.

The workaround is simply to remove the tty and pipe to cat:

```
aws help |cat
```

see:
https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/4972